# Connecting data from mouse hover pop up data on a States Map for generating PIE chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am new to D3js and I need help how can I get
the value of mouse hover pop up data on a STATE MAP and at the same time, it  will generate a PIE chart . Any kind of help would be appreciated

http://jsfiddle.net/2emnt8m3/16/ -- 1 dataset is available for Map, I want those data, which will generate a pie based on pop up data.

This is for Pie chart:

```
{
    "label": "Assault on women ",
    "value": 64131,
    "color": "#1ee675"
},
{
    "label": "Dowry Deaths",
    "value": 57618,
    "color": "#44b9ae"
},
{
    "label": "Cruelty",
    "value": 18812,
    "color": "#7b37c0"
}];
```

The above value is taken for sample for pie chart. But it should return the pop up data on mouse hover so that it will generate a PIE chart for every data pop up on mouse hover.

In the dataset, There are 34 states and 6 crimehead varaibles with DATA from 2001 to 2012. Just say for 2001, I select state: Andhra pradesh on mouse hover, Below data would pop up and I want these data to generate for PIE chart in the same time.
This is for map chart:

```
STATEUTS:"Andhra Pradesh",
RAPE:871,
Kidnapping:765,
Dowry:420,
Assault:3544,
Insult:2271,
Cruelty:5791,
Importation:7,
ImmoralT:1332,
Prohibtion:551,
Total:16477,
Year:2001
```

Here is one of the example I have look on:
http://simonbjohnson.github.io/Ebola_Dashboard/

[image: Map Hover Line chart Generate]

Comment: Fixed indenting and removed excessive use of bold.

Comment: Can you be more specific about your problem?

Comment: The problem is :; How can I get the pop up DATA on mouse hover from MAP chart so that I can used the same data at the same time for generating PIE chart. Whenever the mouse hover to any STATE, the PIE chart also should change according to the pop up data. Dataset is in below link.   http://jsfiddle.net/h0rnzk4s/8/    difficult to me is how can I call the DATA from MAP chart .